# Argument of type numbering is not assignable to parameter of type string

Tags: angular, typescript

I have three arrays called,

```
let averageReport: any = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let maleData: Array<any> = [];
let femaleData: Array<any> = [];
```

I loop through average report and push values to maleData and femaleData. I declared the array types as any but still typescript is complaining that "Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'"
There are similar questions with the same question title as this but this is not same as those questions.

here is the [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztyrcb?file=src/app/app.component.ts) on stackblitz

code,

```
ngOnInit() {
    let averageReport: any = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    let maleData: Array<any> = [];
    let femaleData: Array<any> = [];
    let dateNow = new Date();
    let startDate = new Date(dateNow.getTime() - 20000);
    averageReport
      .map(
        x => {
          if (x === 1) {
            femaleData.push(
              {
                x: parseInt(startDate.getTime() / 1000), // here is the propblem
                y: x.result
              })
          }
          if (x === 2) {
            maleData.push(
              {
                x: parseInt(startDate.getTime() / 1000),
                y: x.result
              })
          }
        }
      )
  }
```

Comment: `parseInt` expects a string, but you've already got a number so it won't compile. If you're just trying to round it, use `Math.round` instead

Comment: it doesn't look like a good practice to fill an array inside a .map()...

Comment: why so? can i use foreach?

Comment: `for(let report of averageReport) { ... }`

Comment: why not i use foreach? or even map?

Comment: you have to declare a new function inside a foreach, whereas you don't have to in a for-of, so the scope is easier to understand

Comment: why not with map?

Comment: @Random That's a matter of opinion. Many people find the functional syntax clearer, especially when a named function is used instead of an anonymous one

Comment: `.map()` is made for something completely different. One would expect your function to return a new object, and to store it in a new array. `.map()` is made to transform an array of object into an array of string for instance...

Comment: can you answer my question?

Comment: @user184994 outside a class, I would agree it may be clearer, but my main concern is to clearly know what "this" refers to, as it is the question of life in JS language... :) But indeed, that's a matter of opinion

Comment: @Random That's why we have fat arrow syntax

Comment: One more thing, what is `x.result` supposed to do ?

Comment: It is not supposed to do anything. You can ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with this:
I changed "Array" to "any[]", changed .map to for-of, and parseInt to Math.round

```
ngOnInit() {
    let averageReport: any = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    let maleData: any[] = [];
    let femaleData: any[] = [];
    let dateNow = new Date();
    let startDate = new Date(dateNow.getTime() - 20000);
    for(let report of averageReport) {
          if (report === 1) {
            femaleData.push(
              {
                x: Math.round(startDate.getTime() / 1000), // here is the propblem
                y: report.result
              })
          }
          if (report === 2) {
            maleData.push(
              {
                x: Math.round(startDate.getTime() / 1000),
                y: report.result
              })
          }
    }
  }
```